Angular V18: NullInjectorError: No provider for _NgZone
I'm currently in the process of upgrading from Angular version 17 to version 18.0.0. One of my components relies on the NgZone import from @angular/core."
for example-
  this.ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.expand()
      }, 0);
    });

angular.json have configuration like "polyfills": ["zone.js"].
But when run apps getting error on browser dev tool console.
NullInjectorError: No provider for _NgZone!
Feel free to inform me if any additional information is required. Could you please assist with this?
Thanks!

Ensure you have provideZoneChangeDetection added to the providers array of ApplicationConfig.
App.config.ts
import { ApplicationConfig, provideZoneChangeDetection } from '@angular/core';
import { provideRouter } from '@angular/router';

import { routes } from './app.routes';

export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [provideZoneChangeDetection({ eventCoalescing: true }), provideRouter(routes)]
};

Component Code:
import { Component, NgZone, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrl: './app.component.css',
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'test';

  constructor(private ngZone: NgZone) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        alert('zone hi!');
      }, 0);
    });
  }
}

Stackblitz Demo -> cd test -> npm I && npm run start

If you are using the modular method, then ensure your main.ts file looks like the below
MAIN.TS
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule, {
  ngZoneEventCoalescing: true
})
  .catch(err => console.error(err));

Stackblitz Demo -> cd modular -> npm I && npm run start

I am using the modular method and did changes as per MAIN.TS above but still have the same error.

@cjdevin try comparing the code in the stackblitz with your code, mainly package.json, angular.json to see if there is any version mismatch, or incorrect configuration, also check if zone.js is installed!

compared every configuration, and the above demo seems to be true to me. However, the ng build and bundle file expose element used inside the shell container are causing this error rather than the ng serve. Any thoughts?
